# PYTHON Problem: Why is my code showing "NONE" when line no. 9 is executed? can anyone assist me?

Tags: python

```
print("\tWELCOME TO DRY_RUN CLASS ASSAIGNTMENT!\t")
userList = []

def mainSystem():
    number = 1
    userInput = int(input("Enter the size of the List: "))
    if userInput > 0:
        for x in range(0, userInput):
            variable = int(input(print("Enter number",number )))
            number = number + 1
            userList.append(variable)

    else:
        print("Number should not be less than or equal to '0'!")

def maxAll():
    maxofall = 0
    for element in userList:
        if element > maxofall:
            maxofall = element
    print("The maximum number is:", element)

while True:
    mainSystem()
    askUser = int(input("What do you want to do with the numbers?\n1.Max All\n2.Average\n3.Quit\nYour answer: "))
    if askUser == 1:
        maxAll()
```

this is the code i am using right now...
what do i need to fix i am getting an error like this wheni am executing line no. 9
:-
Enter Number *whatever the number is*
None*input starts here*
???

Comment: remove the `print()`,  Why do you decide to add `print` here and not with other `input()` calls? Use f-string or string formatting or string concatenation to construct the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

```
def mainSystem():
    number = 1
    userInput = int(input("Enter the size of the List: "))
    if userInput > 0:
        for x in range(0, userInput):
            variable = int(input("Enter number {} : ".format(number) ))
            number = number + 1
            userList.append(variable)

    else:
        print("Number should not be less than or equal to '0'!")
```

Change your function to this.

`print()` is a function. Which returns nothing (`None`) in your case.
`input()` function thinks this `None` object is worth displaying on console.

Hence None appears on screen before taking any input.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems:

1)You have a misplaced print() inside input() in your mainSystem() function

2)You probably want to use f-strings to print the right number instead of the string literal 'number'

```py
def mainSystem():
    number = 1
    userInput = int(input("Enter the size of the List: "))
    if userInput > 0:
        for x in range(0, userInput):
            variable = int(input(f"Enter number {number} : ")) 
            number = number + 1
            userList.append(variable)
```